# How to develop the flowing logic?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

1. Created new document in firebase firestore (fields: message, sendTo, time).
2. Automatically, flutter SMS app triggered.
3. App automatically getData (field values) from Firebase and pass the values to sms function.
4. SMS function is called:

   SmsMessage smsMessage = new SmsMessage(sendTo, message);
   sender.sendSms(smsMessage);

AUTOMATICALLY SEND SMS FROM ANDROID WHEN A DOCUMENT IS CREATED IN FIREBASE

```
sendSMS() async {
if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  setState(() {
    SmsSender sender = new SmsSender();

    String address = etPhoneNumber.text;
    etPhoneNumber.text.isEmpty ? validate = true : validate = false;

    String message = etMessage.text;

    etMessage.text.isEmpty ? validate = true : validate = false;

    SmsMessage smsMessage = new SmsMessage(address, message);

    smsMessage.onStateChanged.listen((state) {
      if (state == SmsMessageState.Sent) {
        //showToast("SMS Sent");

      } else if (state == SmsMessageState.Delivered) {
        // showToast("SMS Not Sent");
      }
    });
    sender.sendSms(smsMessage);

    createRoom(address);
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> smsDataMap = {
    "message": etMessage.text,
    "sendTo": etPhoneNumber.text,
    "time": DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
  };

  databaseMethods.addSmsInfo(smsDataMap);
}
etMessage.clear();
etPhoneNumber.clear();
```

}
}

The above code is working when I click the send button but, I would like to know how this can be triggered automatically.

Comment: From your description it's not clear when this should be triggered automatically. By what I can see, you could use a cloud function to send the SMS with a trigger on the firebase doc creation https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore. Is this similar to the use case you are refering?